# Careers Account Delete Request

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, user-accounts

My main Open ID URL is associated with [this Careers account](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/info/118958).

However, the Careers account I seem to have actually created is [this one](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/info/129201). I think what should probably happen is that the first account should be deleted, and then I can change the second one's OpenID to my main one (and then be able to link it to my other SE accounts).

So please delete this account on Careers: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/info/118958.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've merged your accounts, so you should be all set.

Comment: How is it we can't delete the account directly from the website ?